# Please explain unravel_index when order='F'

Tags: python, function, numpy, indexing, numpy-ufunc

I understood unravel_index in general but don't get how this example works :

`np.unravel_index([31, 41, 13], (7,6), order='F')`

Answer (score 0):

C layout:

```
In [447]: np.arange(42).reshape(7,6)                                                           
Out[447]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]])
In [448]: np.unravel_index([31, 41, 13], (7,6), order='C')                                     
Out[448]: (array([5, 6, 2]), array([1, 5, 1]))
```

F layout:

```
In [450]: np.arange(42).reshape(7,6,order='F')                                                 
Out[450]: 
array([[ 0,  7, 14, 21, 28, 35],
       [ 1,  8, 15, 22, 29, 36],
       [ 2,  9, 16, 23, 30, 37],
       [ 3, 10, 17, 24, 31, 38],
       [ 4, 11, 18, 25, 32, 39],
       [ 5, 12, 19, 26, 33, 40],
       [ 6, 13, 20, 27, 34, 41]])
In [451]: np.unravel_index([31, 41, 13], (7,6), order='F')                                     
Out[451]: (array([3, 6, 6]), array([4, 5, 1]))
```